# Remove .php from url WITH exceptions (htaccess)

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ account.php?username=$1
```

This basically serves my user profiles so like twitter someone can just type: url.com/theirusername

However I want to make certain pages like /home not lead to a profile but a different .php page, again without the .php at the end.

Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have another rule to add `.php` **before this rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

# To internally redirect file to file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# handle profile URLs    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ account.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

just add more rules to match all the other pages, put it before the rule for usernames.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home$ home.php
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ account.php?username=$1
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I've used the first answer in the end.